# Sharepoint 2007 : Saving Form data with page redirection using custom parameters

Tags: forms, save, sharepoint-2007

After saving the form data I would like to **REDIRECT** to different pages based on the @Status value  using the input type button.

```
<input  type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={**Confirm.aspx?ID=1**}')};" />

if @Status == "Draft"

    url = "draft.aspx ? ID = " @ID

else if @Status == "Save"

     url = "save.aspx ? ID = " @ID 

else 

    url = "confirm.aspx ? ID = " @ID
```

Here @ID and @Status are share point list column names

Now I have hard-coded the url **Confirm.aspx?ID=4**. But I want to check the status value using XSLT condition and set different URL name with **@ID** value.. How do I achieve this..

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `url = "{@Status}.aspx ? ID = {@ID}`" ?

If it is not please elabrate your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. actually I am looking some thing different 

Redirect the page based on the status value 

In XSLT how do I check 

IF @Status = "Draft"
 
{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('_commit;_redirect={*DRAFT.aspx?ID=@ID}')};


ELSE IF @status = "Save"


 {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('_commit;_redirect={*SAVE.aspx?ID=@ID}')};

ELSE IF @status = Submit"


 {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('_commit;_redirect={*SUBMIT.aspx?ID=@ID}')};

 
 

Hope you got some problem